# Create anaconda environment identical to existing python environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a python 3.4 environment with very specific packages installed. Is there a straight forward way to create an anaconda environment will all the same packages without creating a python environment then manually installing the packages. e.g..

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4
conda activate myenv 
conda install beautifulsoup4==4.6.1
```

I'd like to do this as i want to share a python script and make it as easy as possible for others to run it.

These are all the packages installed in my python3.4 environment

```
'altgraph==0.16.1', 
'asn1crypto==0.24.0', 
'beautifulsoup4==4.6.1', 
'certifi==2018.4.16', 
'cffi==1.11.5', 
'chardet==3.0.4', 
'configargparse==0.13.0', 
'cryptography==2.3', 
'defusedxml==0.5.0', 
'dis3==0.1.3', 
'future==0.17.1', 
'h5py==2.8.0', 
'idna==2.7', 
'jira==2.0.0', 
'macholib==1.11', 
'numpy==1.15.3', 
'oauthlib==2.1.0', 
'pbr==4.2.0', 
'pefile==2018.8.8', 
'pycparser==2.18', 
'pyinstaller==3.4', 
'pyjwt==1.6.4', 
'pyqt4==4.11.4', 
'pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0', 
'pywin32==220', 
'regex==2018.07.11', 
'requests-oauthlib==1.0.0', 
'requests-toolbelt==0.8.0', 
'requests==2.19.1', 
'six==1.11.0', 
'urllib3==1.23', 
'xmltodict==0.11.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conda-env` is your friend:

`conda-env export -n orig > orig.yml`

where `orig` is the name of the environment you want to clone, followed by

`conda-env create -n new -f=orig.yml`

where `new` is the new name of the copy.  The file `orig.yml` contains everything about the environment you want to copy: dependencies, installed packages incl. version, and such.